# C# remove invisible chars from NetworkStream

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, stream, networkstream

I'm making a simple command program, and while trying to create a directory, I'm getting the error that there is invalid characters in the path, I'm guessing the NetworkStream added invisible characters?

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine(">> Recieved: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
byte[] back = null;
if (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length).Contains("cd "))
{
    try
    {
        back = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(">> Created Directory");
        stream.Write(back, 0, back.Length);
        string dir = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length).Replace("cd ", "");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

EXACT ERROR: System.Argument Exception, Illegal Characters at Path

Comment: why don't use inspect the string in your debugger?

Comment: It's using invisible chars. I wouldn't be able to see them regardless.

Comment: yes, you would. convert to byte array (or whatever you like)

Comment: at one point you decide it's ASCII then convert to UTF8. which is it?

Comment: I have converted it to UTF8, and I'm still getting the same error, thanks for pointing that out, though.

Comment: Can share 'inspected' dir ?

Answer (score 1):

Put `dir.ToCharArray()` in the debugger watch expression.  You'll now see the individual character codes, including the non-printable ones like 0.